# How to extract more than 1 variable from Python launched in SQL-query to SQL-table

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, ssms

Would you prompt, how to extract to SQL more than 1 variable meaning from Python script written in SQL (e.g. tn -variable. Actually, I want to extract 6 variables).
The query below perfectly extracts the meaning of  1 variable - dataset_with_pred2.

I've tried to list the variables via comma but faced the error: 
Msg 39012, Level 16, State 1, Line 92

> Unable to communicate with the runtime for 'Python' script. Please
>   check the requirements of 'Python' runtime. Query was canceled by
>   user.

Thank you very much.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_name]
           ([col1]
           ,[col2]
           ,[...]
           ,[coln])
exec sp_execute_external_script  
   @language =N'Python',    
   @script=N'

#python script here 
...
tn = 5
dataset_with_pred2 = dataframe
'
,
   @input_data_1=N'

select col1
      ,col2
 from dbo.table_name
 '
   ,@input_data_1_name = N'df'
,@output_data_1_name =  N'dataset_with_pred2'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to put out of the Python script only 1 variable meaning. And the variable type should always be pandas Dataframe.
This means, if you want to extract from Python script something but a table (e.g. string), you will have to put it into a table and then extract it from a table.

Unfortunatelly, I found only documentation in Russian. Hope, in your country the link will redirect you in English version: [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)